# How to get data from html table to function using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I facing the problem on how i ganna code this. I tried to do `google.script.run` but not working. When i click the button Approved, the button will throw data to the function. I dont know what to do next. I have no more idea how it works. Thanks!

**Index.html**

```
<body>
    <div  id="tables">
      <? var data = getData();?>
      <table id="tableShift1">
      <caption >Shift1</caption>
          <th>   ID   </th>
          <th>   Ldap   </th>
          <th>   Action   </th>
        <? for (var dataList = 1; dataList < data.length; dataList++) {
             ?>
          <tr >
            <td><?= data[dataList][0] ?></td>
            <td><?= data[dataList][1] ?></td>
            <td><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved(data[dataList][0])' id='btnLdap'>Approve</button></td>
          </tr>
        <?   
          } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function setApproved(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE');
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

 var headers = values[0];
 var ldapIndex = headers.indexOf('ID'); 
 var statusIndex = headers.indexOf('approvalstatus');

 var sheetRow;

 for( var i = 1 ; i < values.length; i++ )
 {
   var row = values[i];
   if(row[ldapIndex] == data)
   { 
     sheetRow = i +1;
     break;
   }
}
 ++statusIndex;
 sheet.getRange(sheetRow, statusIndex).setValue('Approved');
}
```

Comment: Explain clearly what it is you're trying to do, and what actually happens when you run the above code.

Comment: I cant get the data from the table when i click the button Approve. `<td><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved(data[dataList][0])' id='btnLdap'>Approve</button>` this is the code in html im facing now. i dont know how i ganna code to get the data i want. Sorry in my english.

Comment: In should be this, `'google.script.run.setApproved("<?= data[dataList][0] ?>")'`. Try that

Comment: It works! Thanks @Jack Brown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the following

```
<td><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved(data[dataList][0])' id='btnLdap'>Approve</button>
```

Since, the value of data[dataList][0] needs to be send. We need to use printing scriptlets to define the exact value at the time of html evaluation.
It should be:

```
<td><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved("<?= data[dataList][0] ?>")' id='btnLdap'>Approve</button>
```